# Draggable table tr is not moved in vue.js

Tags: html-table, vue.js, draggable, vuejs2

I use vue.js 2.0 and I made draggable table using [Vue.Draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable).
It has no error, but when I try to drag `tr`, it is not moved. But using `div` then it moved. Did I have something missed?

*index.html*

```
<div id="service-list">
<table>
    <draggable :list="services" :element="'tbody'"> 
       <tr v-for="service in services">
          <td>{{ service.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ service.price }}</td>
       </tr>
    </draggable>
</table>
</div>
```

*app.js*

```
var service_list = new Vue({
    el: '#service-list',
    data: {
    services: []
},
mounted: function() {
    var that = this;
    $.get({
        url: 'use my url',
        success: function(res) {
            that.services = res;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/61 this pretty much solves the issue. Seems like you have to wrap the table and the td's in their own components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this same issue.  Things worked fine if I used `div` but not when I tried to use `tr`'s.  This was the case even after I discovered the `element` setting.

As Marius pointed out in his comment, [GitHub Issue #61](http://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/61) resolved the issue for me.

What appears to be the issue, is that your `draggable` HTML code is in `index.html` vs a template.  When I moved my code into a template, it started working.

It's not perfectly clear to me why this template requirement exists only for the `table` case, and not the `div` case.

In the GitHub issue, [the author refers](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/61#issuecomment-285901998) to this portion of the Vue documentation: [DOM Template Parsing Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats)

The author also provides a table example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dede89/L54yu3L9/).

For what it is worth... I was able to get dragging to work on tables using [vue-sortable](http://sagalbot.github.io/vue-sortable/) without this requirement of using templates.  The downside with vue-sortable, is that it hasn't been maintained and updated for Vue2. I found a [workaround](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-sortable/issues/10#issuecomment-272709457) to get it installed with Vue2.  Once installed, it was simpler to work with, but had fewer features.

Answer (score 6):

I ended up on this issue multiple times when going through a simple addition of draggable. Couple of things I noticed are not mentioned on the [github issue 61](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/61) and here but they are surely in [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats).

1. When you are adding table you need to keep the template to standard html so you cannot have draggable element and a tr inside it. You should use `is="draggable"` as an attribute on tbody.
2. `tag="tbody"` is used even on tbody to render tbody tag otherwise draggable would still work but you will not have tbody tag.

Given above I setup an [example fiddle of 3 tables](https://jsfiddle.net/farrukhsubhani/q9bsm78L/). I have tested it with table/list and divs so linking to 3 tables example here. First two tables are linked with `group="people"` so you can drag and drop between them and the last one is independent. Just to show what grouping does.

Thanks to above answers they did help me get to this point.

Answer (score 2):

## What worked for me:

#### HTML

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Sport</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody is="draggable" :list="list" tag="tbody">
    <tr
      v-for="item in list"
      :key="item.id"
    >
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.sport }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### JS

```html
<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    ...,
    data: {
      list: [
        { id: 1, name: "Abby", sport: "basket" },
        { id: 2, name: "Brooke", sport: "foot" },
        { id: 3, name: "Courtenay", sport: "volley" },
        { id: 4, name: "David", sport: "rugby" },
      ],
    },
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="service-list">
<table>
       <tr v-for="service in services" is="draggable" :list="services" :element="'tbody'" >
          <td>{{ service.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ service.price }}</td>
       </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

use this instead. i hope this could help you.

Comment: Could you add a link to documentation for reference or an explanation how this code works/solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to docs:
https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/example/components/table-example.vue

```
<draggable v-model="list" tag="tbody">
      <tr v-for="item in list" :key="item.name">
        <td scope="row">{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.sport }}</td>
      </tr>
    </draggable>
```